# Stuck with how to calculate a mode from an array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am stuck with a problem where I am supposed to figure out a mode from an array in typescript.

I am using the program Visual Studio Code and I know that I need a for loop but I am unsure what I should loop through it. I also have to make sure that if the array is empty, the number that always shows up is 0 and if there is two integers that show up the same amount of times, that the smaller number (whether positive or negative) is the number that is put as the mode.

Currently I have this part of the code:

```
export let mode = (a: number[]): number => {

    let mode: number;

    mode = a[0];
    if (a.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < a. length; i++) {
        if ()

        return mode;
};
```

I know that there needs to be an if statement after the for loop that changes the mode when necessary, but I am unsure beyond that.

Comment: So is it supposed to return the number with most occurrence in the given array?

Comment: Yep, I don't believe I gave an array, but it can find the most common number no matter the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you indicated: your `mode` should be a function which:

- accepts an array of numbers and should return the number with highest occurrence.
- if there are two or more numbers that share the highest occurrence, then it should return the number with the least value.
- if the given array is empty, it should return 0.

You could do this:

1. If given array is empty, return 0 right away. Else proceed with the rest of the steps.
2. Count the occurrences of each number in the array.
3. Sort the result of #2 by number of occurrence and value. Sort by highest occurrence, then lowest value.
4. Get the first of the items from #3.

Here's an implementation using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do step #2, and [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do step #3.

```
let mode = (numbers: number[]): number => {

    if (numbers.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    const m = numbers.reduce((items, current) => {
        const item = (items.length === 0) ? null : items.find((x) => x.value === current);
        (item) ? item.occurrence++ : items.push({ value: current, occurrence: 1 });
        return items;
    }, [])
    .sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.occurrence < b.occurrence) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a.occurrence > b.occurrence || a.value < b.value) {
              return -1;
        } else {
            return (a.value === b.value) ? 0 : 1;
        }
    });

    return m[0].value;
}
```